# c++11 what is the scope for the lambda function below

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

quick question on lambda functions. I saw that when using the gcc complier there is an implicit cast to a function pointer for the operator() function of the lambda if it doesn't have a capture.  As a result looking at this watered down example below what should I expect the life time of this function to be available for callback? What scope is the lambda function defined at? local scope, package scope, global scope? Is there any problem with calling the lambda after the function exits in this case? I am not looking to use std::function here at all, so please don't respond with a std::function return value for a solution. My question is really just to understand the scope of that function (without capture) and if it is available for the lifetime of the program.

```
#include <iostream>
typedef int(*fPtrT)(int,int);     

 fPtrT fx() { 
    return static_cast<fPtrT>([](int i, int j){return i+j;});
 }

int main()
{
    std::cout << fx()(5,2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `fx()` function creates an `r-value` variable, the scope of which lasts for the duration of `main()`.

Comment: @cmbasnett thanks but that much I know, I was asking what scope is the lambda object itself created that the compiler creates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lambda expression returns an instance of an anonymously-defined class (the type is known only to the compiler). This class overloads the `operator ()` to serve as a [function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B).

On top of that, lambda expressions that don't close over any state have the added specification that they can be implicitly converted to a C-style function pointer. In those cases, imagine that the `operator ()` just invokes a static function (and the implicit conversion is a pointer to that static function).

Knowing all of this, we can say the following things about the code you posted:

- Every time the `fx` function is invoked, an instance of the anonymous class is created

  - This instance is an r-value; as such it only exists until the end of the statement
- The function pointer returned by the `fx` function is effectively a pointer to a static function
- The function pointer can be safely used by whoever has possession of it (because it is a static function with no shared state)

Comment: +1 this statement helps "In those cases, imagine that the operator () just invokes a static function (and the implicit conversion is a pointer to that static function)."

Answer (score 3):

A lambda that doesn't capture anything is safe to use anywhere.

If it captures by reference then it's only safe within the lifetime of the objects it refers to.

If it captures by value then it's safe anywhere – it's just an object.